# jQuery check CSS color value not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm using jQuery to check if a particular CSS property and value exist. Why doesn't it work? I'm expecting to see the 'yes' log.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  if ($('p').css('color') === 'blue') {
    console.log('yes');
  } else {
    console.log('no');
  }
});
```

```css
p {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>text</p>
```

Comment: Your color is coming back as RGB, hence checking for blue won't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your color is coming back as an RGB value, not the name of the color. You'll want to do a comparison against the RGB string instead.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
var color = $('p').css('color');
console.log(color);
if (color === 'rgb(0, 0, 255)') {
    console.log('yes');
  } else {
    console.log('no');
  }
});
```

```css
p {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>text</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate `document.styleSheets`, check if `cssRules` `.selectorText` is equal to `"p"`, then check if `.style` `.color` property is equal to `"blue"`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  for (let {cssRules: [{selectorText, style:{color}}]} of document.styleSheets) {
    if (selectorText === "p") {
      if (color === "blue") {
        console.log("yes")
      } else {
        console.log("no")
      }
      break;
    }
  }
});
```

```css
p {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>text</p>
```